# Collect cards for beginner deck

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building

i'm willing to dive into MtG

I just ordered Deck Builder's Toolkit from our local club, is that going to be enough for building at least average beginner deck? What my best options to expand my collection from this point?

Comment: This question is likely to be closed due to being primarily opinion based. That being said my favorite way to collect cards is drafting if your local game shop offers it as it allows you to both get new cards and learn the game by playing.

Comment: The answer is going to depend completely on what format(s) you want to participate in and what competitive level ($$).

Comment: As @Fr33dan says, this  is a pretty opinionated question. That said, _in my opinion_, the Deckbuilder's toolkit is probably one of (if not **the**) best way to start a collection from nothing.

Comment: To add to the advice of going drafting, playing the drafting format alongside pre-constructed decks will teach you that the value of a card can differ wildly between formats. Personally this helped me become a lot better at evaluating a card in its context instead of in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a lot worse than the Deckbuilders toolkit for starting out, you will be surprised as well how quickly a collection can start to grow even just buying the odd booster or as said above taking part in local drafts or events. Your best bet for good advice about this would be at your local games store or even better at your local Friday Night Magic. They will welcome a new player and have lots of advice to give, tips, point you in the right direction etc.